mantener el enlace visible como página web
Tengo una hoja de cálculo que contiene una URL por usuario y he intentado buscando bibliografía para poder mantener el enlace visible como página web pero aún no lo logro.
Estaría muy agradecido si se me sugiere para poder realizar lo que necesito. Las direcciones se encuentran en la variable var colT= sheet.getRange(i, 20).getValue();
Comparto mi código
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
  .evaluate()
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
}

function colT() {
   var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('openUrl').setHeight(100);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Abrir Enlace');
}
function submitData(obj){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Wv7V       zchlP-5U7GwNd       IBbtLCrR4yqhYMOfHdVu-8x26Q");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("AsistenciaGeneral");
  var  flag  =  1 ;
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
      for(var i = 1;i <= lr;i++){
  var id = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      if(id == obj){
      flag = 0;

  var colT= sheet.getRange(i, 20).getValue();  
  var colD = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();      
  var colE = sheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
  var colF = sheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
  var colG = sheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
  var colH = sheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
  var colI = sheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
  var colJ = sheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
  var colK = sheet.getRange(i, 11).getValue();
  var colL = sheet.getRange(i, 12).getValue();
  var colM = sheet.getRange(i, 13).getValue();
  var colN = sheet.getRange(i, 14).getValue();
  var colO = sheet.getRange(i, 15).getValue();
  var colP = sheet.getRange(i, 16).getDisplayValue();
  var data ="<table><tr><th colspan=2><center><img src=' 

Me dicen que usando a target _blank url podría lograrlo pero aún no entiendo cómo.La url se encuentra en la variable siguiente: var colT= sheet.getRange(i, 20).getValue();
